# CSS Animation, Positions

Tags: html, css, animation

im trying to apply "shock" animation for image at my website. The problem is that script extends the width so i can see the bottom bar of my browser :

HTML :

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <article class="top-logo">
            <h1>
                <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="robbie-logo"></a>
            </h1>
        </article>
```

CSS:

```
.top-logo {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
.top-logo img {
    height: 150px;
    width: 350px; 
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.top-logo:hover {
  animation-name: diagonal-slide;
  animation-duration: 0.05s;
  animation-iteration-count: 10;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes diagonal-slide {
  from { top: 0; left: 0; animation-timing-function: linear; }
  20% { top: -5px; left: -5px; animation-timing-function: linear; }
  40% { top: 5px; left: -5px; animation-timing-function: linear; }
  60% { top: 5px; left: 5px; animation-timing-function: linear; }
  80% { top: -5px; left: 5px; animation-timing-function: linear; }
  to { top: 0; left: 0; animation-timing-function: linear; }
}
```

Comment: Would be nice to see more complete html/css so the problem can be recreated.

Comment: overflow: hidden; did the job here /close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't happen here (no scroll bars), but still, try to add this to the container:

```
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.top-logo {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}

.top-logo img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 350px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.top-logo:hover {
  animation-name: diagonal-slide;
  animation-duration: 0.05s;
  animation-iteration-count: 10;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes diagonal-slide {
  from {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
  }
  20% {
    top: -5px;
    left: -5px;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
  }
  40% {
    top: 5px;
    left: -5px;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
  }
  60% {
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
  }
  80% {
    top: -5px;
    left: 5px;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <article class="top-logo">
    <h1>
      <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x60/fa0" alt="robbie-logo"></a>
    </h1>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why the OP should consider doing this? What does the extra CSS do in this situation?

Comment: Thanks, overflow: hidden; was the deal :)

Comment: The scrollbars he talks about obvioulsy appear when the animation is triggered, extending the right border of the window. By trying to hide any overflow I am trying to prevent that.

Comment: Thanks. That is helpful.